# Shopify API - Create Fulfillment, One location works, Multiple locations does not

Tags: api, shopify, fulfillment

When using the code below, to fulfil a single location/fulfilment, it works fine.

If an order has 2 fulfilments (from 2 locations), it does not work saying "None of the items are stocked at the new location."

**location_id and the single fulfillment_order_id are both specified.**

**Stock is 'in stock' at the location too.**

**The same stock lines, on a single fulfilment order, go through fine.**

URL: https://.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-04/orders/<order_id>/fulfillments.json

```
{"fulfillment":{"location_id":99999999041,"tracking_number":"https://tracking.com/5678","tracking_urls":["https://tracking.com/5678"],"notify_customer":true, "line_items_by_fulfillment_order":[{ "fulfillment_order_id":9999999999053,"fulfillment_order_line_items": [{"id":99999999990725,"quantity":1},{"id":99999999993493,"quantity":1},{"id":9999999997957,"quantity":1}] }] }}
```

**EDIT**: To clarify, if an order has 2 fulfilments (from 2 locations), it does not work - why?

**EDIT**: A solution was found, that if the other fulfilment (by the users own custom location) is created in the backend of shopify, then the above fulfilment code goes through fine.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: If an order has 2 fulfilments (from 2 locations), it does not work.

Comment: Usually you will get a fulfillmentOrder and it is then up to you to create fulfillments that satisfy. You would likely be wanting to fulfill each location separately. Have you tried that?